# LeftBarButtonItems Unresponsive

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have 4 UIBarButtonItems inside a UISplitViewController's right hand side (the detail controller). I'm using a UINavigationViewController to control the views in the right hand side, and adding the buttons to one of the ViewController's which I'm pushing in their viewDidLoad. The buttons appear fine, but are totally unresponsive. I have the same UIBarButtonItems in the right items which respond as expected. I could understand if it was just one dodgy button but all four makes me think something is amiss.

I'm setting the buttons with:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:leftActionButtons animated:true]; // this is an NSArray
```

Comment: @MDT true and YES both evaluate to 1

Comment: @Nick good point, I'll admit to being ignorant of that, just thought it might help because I've personally never used anything but animated:YES. I learned something out of this!

Comment: Unresponsive means they do not even change visual state when clicked or they do not execute targeted selectors?

Comment: The not changing visual state was what made me suspicious too. Bizarrely, adding one button to the array twice called all four to be totaly unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarrely, adding one button to the array twice called all four to be totally unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set targets and selectors on those buttons? That's a more helpful bit of code to post than the `setLeftBarButtonItems:` line.